# Исключить слово в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте.

К примеру есть текст:

```
[ SIMPLE TRUTH [ DEMO VIEW ] ]
```

Вывести должно только [ DEMO VIEW ], так как внутри скобок нет слова TRUTH.
Помогите написать сие выражение.

Comment: .

    (?!\[[^\]]*?TRUSH[^\]]*\])\[[^\]]*\]

Comment: Не работает.

Comment: Исправьте опечатку (TRUSH на TRUTH) и заработает.

Comment: Не заметил. Спасибо, работает.

Comment: А хотя нет. Если даже будет слово TRU, то регулярка пример это за TRUTH

Comment: Не примет. Полное наличие слова обязательное условие исключения совпадения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать регулярные выражения для матча негативных выражений довольно проблематично, тем более у вас возможны рекурсивные варианты, скобки внтури скобок.

Значительно проще сделать парсинг этих скобок с помощью конечного автомата и затем просто проверять наличие слова TRUTH в строке.

Как то так:

```
function prepareData($str, &$data, $offset = 0)
{
    $l = strlen($str);
    $buf = '';
    for ($i = $offset; $i < $l; $i++) {
        $char = $str[$i];
        switch ($char) {
            case '[':
                $buf .= substr($str, $offset, $i - $offset);
                $offset = $i = prepareData($str, $data, $i + 1) + 1;
            break;
            case ']':
                $buf .= substr($str, $offset, $i - $offset);
                $data[] = $buf;
                return $i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

$str = '[ SIMPLE TRUTH [ DEMO VIEW ] [ ANOTHER DEMO ] DEMO ] [ THIRD DEMO ] ';
$data = array();
prepareData($str, $data);
print_r($data);

foreach ($data as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, 'TRUTH') === false) {
        echo $line."\n";
    }
}
```

Вывод будет следующий:

`Array
(
    [0] =>  DEMO VIEW 
    [1] =>  ANOTHER DEMO 
    [2] =>  SIMPLE TRUTH   DEMO 
    [3] =>  THIRD DEMO 
)
 DEMO VIEW 
 ANOTHER DEMO 
 THIRD DEMO`

Comment: Можно поподробней. Не понял Вас.

Comment: дополнил ответ.